# Navigator.onGenerateRoute was null Flutter

Tags: flutter

i am using

```
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                  AllCategoryScreen.routeName,
                )),
// route generator
    class AppRouter {
    const AppRouter._();

    static Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case MainScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MainScreen());
        break;
      case HomeScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen());
        break;
      case WelcomeScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => WelcomeScreen());
        break;
      case LoginScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen());
        break;
      case RegisterScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RegisterScreen());
        break;
      case ResetPasswordScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ResetPasswordScreen());
        break;
      case ChangePasswordScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ChangePasswordScreen());
        break;
      case OtpScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OtpScreen());
        break;
      case ProductDetailsScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ProductDetailsScreen());
        break;
      case FavoriteScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FavoriteScreen());
        break;
      case ChatsScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ChatsScreen());
        break;
      case AllCategoryScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AllCategoryScreen());
        break;
      case AddNewAdScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AddNewAdScreen());
        break;
      case AddAdSearchScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AddAdSearchScreen());
        break;
      default:
        throw const RouteException("Page Not Found");
     }
     }
     }
```

but I'm getting this error
Navigator.onGenerateRoute was null, but the route named "/all-category-screen" was referenced.

and I am using bloc for managing the auth state if Authenticated or not I don't know if this is the problem or not

Comment: ' 
  static Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case MainScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MainScreen());
        break;

      default:
        throw const RouteException("Page Not Found");
    }
  }
'

Comment: yes 
i think i know what i did wrong I am using 
the app navigator using bloc
'''
 Navigator(
          pages: [
            if (state is Unauthenticated)
              MaterialPage(
                child: BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) =>
                      AuthCubit(sessionCubit: context.read<SessionCubit>()),
                  child: AuthNavigator(),
                ),
              ),
            if (state is Authenticated) MaterialPage(child: MainScreen())
          ],
          onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
        );
'''

Comment: and I must use this idea in the whole app 
I am new to the bloc and found this new idea app navigator good 
but now I wanna change the whole app to this navigator

any idea ?